# No return in AJAX after calling another function inside a function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, email

I have a function for changing your email address basically working as updating the user table in the database and sending an email to the new email address through Codeigniter's Email Library.

Everything seems to be working fine; updating the user table in the database and sending the email to the new email address. But the problem is, my AJAX doesn't receive any return value or whatsoever.

I tried merging the two functions (updating the email, sending an email to the new email address), but still no good.

I tried messing with the return values just to be sure but still my AJAX wont console anything.

Here's my Javascript code:

```
$('#save_email').click(function(){
    if ($('#verified').val()==1) {
        if ($('#register_email').val()=='') {
            $("#register_email").css({"color":"red","border":"1px solid red"});
            toastr.options.timeOut = 5000;
            toastr.error('Email address is empty.', 'Error');
        } else {
            if (!validateEmail($('#register_email').val())){
                $("#register_email").css({"color":"red","border":"1px solid red"});
                toastr.options.timeOut = 5000;
                toastr.error('Invalid email structure.', 'Error');
            } else {
                $.post($("#register_email").data('key'), {email:$('#register_email').val()}, function(data) {
                    if (data.ret == 1) {
                        $.post(baseurl + "applicant/profile/update_email", {email:$('#register_email').val()}, function(data) {
                            console.log(data.ret);
                            if (data.ret == 1) {
                                toastr.options.timeOut = 5000;
                                toastr.success('Email successfully saved.', 'Success');
                                var delay = 1500; 
                                setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(true); }, delay);
                            } else {
                                toastr.options.timeOut = 5000;
                                toastr.error('Error occured.', 'Error');
                            }
                        }, 'json');
                    } else {
                        toastr.options.timeOut = 5000;
                        toastr.error('Email is already in use.', 'Error');
                    }
                }, 'json');

            }
        }
    } else {
        $("#register_email").css({"color":"red","border":"1px solid red"});
        toastr.options.timeOut = 5000;
        toastr.error('Verify email address first.', 'Error');
    }
});
```

Here's my two functions in the controller:

For updating the email address

```
public function update_email()
{
    $data = array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'verify_code' => random_string('alnum', 8),
        'verified' => 0
    );
    $user = $this->session->userdata('user');
    $user_id = $user['idx'];


    $ret = $this->applicant->update_user($user_id, $data);

    $form_user = array (
        'username' => $this->input->post('email')
    );

    $user = $this->applicant->get_user($form_user);

    $return = $this->confirm_email_send($user);

    $this->session->set_userdata('user', $user);
    $this->session->set_userdata('person_id', $user['person_id']);
    $user_role = $this->applicant->get_user_role($user['idx']);
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_role',strtolower($user_role['role_name']));

    if ($ret) {
        echo json_encode(array('ret'=>1));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('ret'=>0));
    }
}
```

For sending the email to the new email address:

```
public function confirm_email_send($user)
{
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://mail.sample.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'info@sample.com', 
        'smtp_pass' => '*****',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $message = '';
    $message .= '<p> Dear ' . $user['display_name'] . ',</p>';
    $message .= '<p> Confirm your email to activate your Best Workers Account - <a href="' . base_url().'signup/verify/'.$user['verify_code'].'">Click Here</a></p>'; 
    $message .= '<p> or copy and paste the following to your address bar: '. base_url().'signup/verify/'.$user['verify_code'];
    $message .= '<p> Thank you!</p>';

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('info@sample.com'); 
    $this->email->to($user['email']);
    $this->email->subject('Action Required - Best Workers Account Verification');
    $this->email->message($message);
    if($this->email->send())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->firephp->log($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

I need some return in my AJAX to fire up the toastr notification.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's developer tools for the response from the PHP?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Status Code: 200 OK.

Comment: What are you expecting for a return?

Comment: @JayBlanchard see my javascript code, it needs the json return ret=>1

Comment: Can you try with the postman? sometimes browsers can not parse /show responses in preview. Also if you remove all server code and just return anything then are you getting anything in response ?

Comment: @Furquan yes i do get a response. after adding the sending email function, i dont get a response anymore

Comment: in your mail function, you are returning "true", try sending any string.

Comment: @Furquan i tried that already. still no ajax response

Comment: One last thing I can think is just to test, remove the last if-else and return "xyz" by default. if it returns anything then maybe you condition ($this->email->send()) is failing

Comment: @Furquan it's not failing, the email is sent. i checked if the email address receives email and it does.

Comment: Can you try to put `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` at the first line in your $.post?